# java: how to write a conditional if statement like "if not (A empty) and (B empty) then"

Tags: java, if-statement

In Java, I need to test that at least 1 of 2 radio groups (radiogroup1 and radiogroup2) is not empty when clicking on a button (i.e., all radio buttons shall not be empty AND at least one radio button is pressed).

The code structure would be something like:

```
button is pressed {
if (radiogroup1 not empty) or (radiogroup2 not empty) {
//do something
}
}
```

If both radiogroups are empty, nothing happens when the button is pressed.

Now, I set up something like this:

```
if  (RadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1 || RadioGroup2.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1) {
//do something
}
```

but I need actually exactly the opposite. I don't succeed to invert the condition with != or something else.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: It's not clear from your question whether you're looking for a positive or a negative.  EITHER just change both `==` to `!=` (if you're looking for a positive), OR change your `||` to `&&` (if you're looking for a negative).  Or clarify your question so you can get a clear answer.

Comment: Java naming conventions have variables and methods beginning with a lower case letter. I thought that RadioGroup was a class with static variable when I first read your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this?

```
            if (!(RadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1 || RadioGroup2.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1))
        {
            //do something
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the logic I was looking for, but for some reason nothing happens when I press the button and a radio button is clicked before. I presume I must fix some other part of the code. I will validate your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?

```
RadioGroup radioGroup1; // assumed initialized someplace else in code
RadioGroup radioGroup2; // assumed initialized someplace else in code

// Check to see if at least one of the two radio groups has a selection
if (radioGroup1.getCheckedRadioButtonId() != -1 || 
    radioGroup2.getCheckedRadioButtonId() != -1) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks yes, this is the logic I meant, but for some reason, the code of the pressed button in '//Do stuff' does not execute, i.e. nothing happens when I press the button and a radio button is clicked before. I presume I must fix some other part of the code.